# How to create a react project using a cloned create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a modified `create-react-app` and I cloned it's repository, how can I create new React project using that cloned repo?

Comment: the README or .md files almost certainly have information about running it locally for the development of CRA

Answer (score 0):

1>> first of all go to your project directory then write **npm install or yarn install**  then

2>> **npm start or yarn start**

if you create a new react app then

1>> **npx create-react-app my-react-app**

2>> and *go to your project dir* cd then press tab now go to your project dir
then **npm start**